# Does XSD import statement override the types in the existing schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

When we use an import statement in an XSD will the imported namespace elements override the types in the current schema?  If yes, can anyone give an example to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2):

No, the point of namespaces is to allow the same name to exist independently and reference distinct definitions.  Therefore, using `xsd:import` provides access to the components defined in the imported namespace without any sort of overriding of the component defined in the importing XSD.  Ambiguity of reference is resolved by requiring use of distinct namespace prefixes prepended to the local component name.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant W3C specification is here : http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/
I recommend that you bookmark the W3C specifications and refer to them regularly.

You can use your favourite search engine to find good tutorials on XML namespaces. Don't forget that the W3C specification is the final authority; tutorials can be misleading or even wrong occasionally.